# Limitations of Bromwich integral for inverting Laplace transform

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, residue-calculus, inverse-laplace

Suppose:
$$f(t)=e^{at}+e^{bt};\quad a>b>0$$

Its Laplace transform is:
$$\mathbf{L}[e^{at}+e^{bt}]=\frac{1}{s-a}+\frac{1}{s-b}$$
for $Re(s)>a$ where $Re$ stands for the real part; for $Re(s)<a$ Laplace transform of $e^{at}+e^{bt}$ doesn't exist because the transform integral isn't finite.

Now suppose we invert $$F(s)=\frac{1}{s-a}+\frac{1}{s-b}$$
using Bromwich integral. $F(s)$ has simple poles at $a,b$, with corresponding residues equal to $1$. Therefore the inverse transform using Bromwich integral would be:
$$\mathbf{L}^{-1}[F(s)]=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_Cds~e^{st}(\frac{1}{s-a}+\frac{1}{s-b})\\
=Res_{s=a}[e^{st}(\frac{1}{s-a}+\frac{1}{s-b})]+Res_{s=b}[e^{st}(\frac{1}{s-a}+\frac{1}{s-b})]\\
=e^{at}+e^{bt}$$

Even though it matches with the $f(t)$ we began with, why is this procedure correct? $F(s)$ is not defined when $Re(s)<a$ and the pole at $b$ lies in the region where $F(s)$ isn't defined. But using the residue at that pole nevertheless gives me $f(t)$ correctly.

My question: Does a transformed function $F(s)$ whose poles lie outside its domain of validity (in the sense that the Laplace transform of the inverted function $f(t)$ has a limited domain of validity in the complex $s$-plane) always give the "correct answer" $f(t)$ when Bromwich integral is evaluated by summing residues?

Since I am not a mathematician I don't how to better phrase my question, but I hope that my example above makes my question clear. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In fact, the domain of validity is defined to lie to the right of all singularities of $F$. It's precisely for that reason that moving the vertical line of integration to the right doesn't change the obtained inverse transform. But we can construct an analytic continuation extending $F$ to the left. Then the residue theorem may be applicable to this continuation.

Comment: @Maxim Why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume we're considering only the one-sided Laplace transform. If $F$ is a Laplace transform, $F$ will be regular to the right of a vertical line, because if the Laplace transform integral converges for $\operatorname{Re} s = \gamma$, it will converge uniformly on any compact subset of $\operatorname{Re} s > \gamma$, giving an analytic function in the half-plane $\operatorname{Re} s > \gamma$.

The function obtained in this way is not defined for $\operatorname{Re} s < \gamma$, so you're correct that there is an intermediate step of constructing an analytic continuation of $F$ before applying the residue theorem.

$1/\sqrt s$ with the branch cut lying in the left half-plane is an example where the inverse transform is well-defined but the residue theorem is not applicable.

If $F$ is meromorphic with finite number of poles and is regular at infinity, it necessarily has a zero at infinity (otherwise the Bromwich integral would diverge), therefore Jordan's lemma applies and the inverse transform can be computed as the sum of the residues of $F$.

If we start with an arbitrary $F$, we do not necessarily get $f$ s.t. $\mathcal L[f] = F$. For instance,
$$\mathcal L^{-1} \!{\left[ \frac {e^s - 1} s \right]} = 0,$$
where the Bromwich integral can be taken over any vertical line.

Comment: ($\mathcal L^{-1} \!{\left[ \frac {e^s - 1} s \right]}(t) =\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\frac{e^s - 1}s e^{st}ds =  1_{t\in [-1,0]}$ for $\sigma > 0$. For  $t = 0,-1$ the integral is $1/2$)

Comment: You're correct, the inverse transform is, strictly speaking, $1/2$ for $t = 0$ and $0$ for $t > 0$. The sign of $\sigma$ doesn't matter.