# Laplace transform, bromwich contour - basic question

Tags: laplace-transform, contour-integration

I am confused about the following two observations which seem
contradictory:

1. It is stated that the region of convergence of the Laplace transform 
   is a half space. That is $L(s)$ is defined for all $s$ with $Re(s)>c$, while
   undefined for all s with $Re(s)<c$.
2. In the discussion of the inverse laplace transform, it is stated that the
   integral
   $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}e^{st}L(s)\mathrm{d}s$$
   can be evaluated by closing the "bromwich contour" (the line of integration) via a
   semicircle to the left of $c$ and then letting the radius tend to infinity.
   (Afterwards using residue theorem)

Now here is my problem: In order for 2.) to be feasible it is necessary that the integrand $e^{st}L(s)$ is defined
on the whole complex plain (because if the radius of the semicircle becomes larger, then eventually every point - even
those points with $Re(s)<<c$ will be enclosed by the circle.). But the Laplace transform L(s) is only defined for $Re(s)>c$.
Hence, how is it possible to use 2.) when $L(s)$ is not defined in some parts of the complex plane?
Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3028672).